# Finding the variance and covariance value between the bands of the image

Tags: image, matlab, covariance, variance

I want to encode without using ready commands. I did something, but the results were too small. I did not compute other bands when errors occurred. I'd appreciate it if you could help.

My V1 (variance-1) value came out at 1,2820183e-05, but with the var() function 91.143653869628900 came out.

```
format long g
img = imread('Landsat8.tif');
blue = round((im2single(img(:, :, 1))+1)*128);
grn = round((im2single(img(:, :, 2))+1)*128);
red = round((im2single(img(:, :, 3))+1)*128);
blue_r = reshape(blue,[2000*2000,1]);
grn_r = reshape(grn,[2000*2000,1]);
red_r = reshape(red,[2000*2000,1]);

%% Mean
mean1 = sum(blue_r)/(2000*2000);
mean2 = sum(grn_r)/(2000*2000);
mean3 = sum(red_r)/(2000*2000);

%% Variance
sum1 = 0;
for i= 1 : length(2000*2000)
   sum1 = sum1 + (blue_r(i) - mean1).^2;
end
V1 = sum1 ./ (length(blue_r));

sum2 = 0;
for i= 1 : length(2000*2000)
    sum2 = sum2 + (grn_r(i) - mean2).^2;
end
V2 = sum2 / (length(grn_r));

%% covariance
sum12 = 0;
for i= 1 : length(2000*2000)
    sum12 = sum12 + (blue_r(i) - mean1) * (grn_r(i) - mean2);
end
c12 = sum12 / (length(blue_r));
```

Comment: `length(2000*2000)` is 1. You should avoid using fixed values always, it just leads to confusion! Use `length(blue_r)`, that is much better than encoding the size with constants. Also, the first channel is red, not blue.

Comment: Landsat-8 has 11 bands. Its band2:Blue, band3=Green, band4=Red. Thank you Cris.

Comment: Before any computation try to convert  variables to double: `img = double(img);`

Comment: Thank you rahnema1. Try to 'img = double(img);' It worked and it true.